# How to (re)insert browser windows into tab bar in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs, window, chromium

In Chromium and other browsers, one can "pull out" individual tabs from a tab bar by click & drag, which creates a separate windows. How does the reverse work? I.e. how does one

1.) insert a browser window into a specific position of another window's tab bar,

2.) drag & drop tabs from one window's tab bar into another window's tab bar?

Preferably no extensions - there should be hotkeys for this.

Comment: How are you planning to do this? Do you have access to Chromium's source code or are you maintaining your own Chromium fork?

Comment: Please read the question. This function is already implented in Chromium